# Increase the thickness of node border in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Suppose I have a node in the shape of a circle. How can I make its border thicker?

```
\node[circle, draw=blue!80, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=12pt] (1) at (0,0) {1};
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The node’s border is a path, you can use the same options for a `\path`, e.g. `ultra thin`, `thick`, `very thick`, and so on:

```
\node[circle, draw=blue!80, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=12pt] (1) at (0,0) {1};
```

The `line width` key works as well:

```
\node[circle,draw=blue!80, line width=1mm, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=12pt] (1) at(0,0) {1};
```

---

All predefined line widths are

```
\tikzset{
    ultra thin/.style= {line width=0.1pt},
    very thin/.style=  {line width=0.2pt},
    thin/.style=       {line width=0.4pt},% thin is the default
    semithick/.style=  {line width=0.6pt},
    thick/.style=      {line width=0.8pt},
    very thick/.style= {line width=1.2pt},
    ultra thick/.style={line width=1.6pt}
}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every node/.append style={circle, draw=blue!80, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=12pt}]
\node                 (1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[thick]          (2) at (1,0) {2};
\node[line width=1mm] (3) at (2,0) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If you have a rectangle as a node (e.g. using matrix in tikz), can you adjust the thickness of the borders individually? E.g. top, bottom, left, right? `line width` changes all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 11):

You can change global path thickness as below, so you no need to change it here and there:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\large]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=2pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   every node/.append style={circle, draw=blue!80, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=12pt}]
\node                 (1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[]               (2) at (1,0) {2};
\node[]               (3) at (2,0) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output (use inkscape tool to covert pdf to png)

[image]

Output (use convert tool to covert pdf to png)

[image]

Comment: How did you get this figure? According your code, numbers should be centered inside circles.

Comment: Really good question. I found it caused by different pdf to png convert tool. one is from inkscape and another is from convert. Not sure if it caused by the default font. I have updated the output from both tool. code is the same but image is really differ.

Comment: @Beatlej `Inkscape` can't use embedded font...