# TikZ reuse code for building nesting pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

This is not new here. But with the solutions in:

- [Problem with overlay when a tikzpicture is inside another tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture/46792#46792)
- [How to typeset a TikZ picture inside a node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node)

I couldn't put it to work.

Basically what I want is to define a command that will be a picture and can be used inside other picture as a node, similarly how the shape is defined. So that I can reuse the code because each picture has many elements. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{ellipsis}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\MUE}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, shape = rectangle, minimum width=15mm, minimum height=7.5mm] (box) {#1};

\draw ($(box.south west)+(0.25,0)$) circle (4pt);
\draw ($(box.south east)-(0.25,0)$) circle (4pt);
\draw[fill=black] ($(box.south west)+(0.25,0)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[fill=black] ($(box.south east)-(0.25,0)$) circle (1pt);

\draw ($(box.north west)+(0.25,0)$) -- +(0,0.25) node[midway] (ant1) {};
\draw ($(box.north east)-(0.25,0)$) -- +(0,0.25) node[midway] (ant2) {};

\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};

\draw (ant1.north) -- +(135:0.25);
\draw (ant1.north) -- +(45:0.25);
\draw (ant2.north) -- +(135:0.25);
\draw (ant2.north) -- +(45:0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\MBS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, shape = dart, shape border rotate = 90, minimum width = 10mm, minimum height = 10mm] (base) {#1};

\draw[line join = round] (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east) -- cycle;

\draw ($(base.north)+(0.5,0)$) -- +(0,0.25) node[midway] (ant1) {};
\draw ($(base.north)-(0.5,0)$) -- +(0,0.25) node[midway] (ant2) {};
\draw[cap = rect, line join = round] (ant1.south) -- (ant2.south);

\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};

\draw (ant1.north) -- +(135:0.25);
\draw (ant1.north) -- +(45:0.25);
\draw (ant2.north) -- +(135:0.25);
\draw (ant2.north) -- +(45:0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, shape = circle, fill = yellow!30] at (0,0) (test1) {\MBS{BS}};

\node[draw, shape = circle, fill = blue!30] at (3,3) (test2) {\MUE{UE1}};
\node[draw, shape = circle, fill = blue!30] at (3,-3) (test3) {\MUE{UE2}};

\draw[->] (test1) -- (test2);
\draw[->] (test1) -- (test3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As it can be seen, the antennas in the picture are not correcly placed because I am using `draw, shape = circle` in the nodes of the second picture. Also, if I add `inner sep = 0pt` the result is even worst. How can I use such kind of nesting inside TikZ?

[image]

Comment: I used the nodes to be easier to place the `\dots`. Can you provide the code?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would use the `ant` nodes to add the last lines to the antenna, just use the last point on the line on which you place the (unnecessary) nodes. — You can also use the `path picture` key to place additional stuff inside a node (provided you know the size of the content before hand) *or* you place first the content and then `fit` the circle around it.

Comment: I would prefer the solution of adding the `v` at the very last point of the antenna. Using nodes helps me in keeping centered the `\dots`. Is there an automatic way to calculate the last point?

Comment: I’ve added an answer. Well, you already have a path to this last point, then you can also place a `coordinate` there and use this when you draw the `v`; or you do `the same path again but without the `--`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use nodes here; neither to mark positions on the path (you can use a `coordinate` for that) nor to get back to the top point on that line, just use the path you already used there (you are allowed to use a path after `node`) or just re-calculate the coordinate or use move-tos to there (leave out the `--` in your path).

I also provide an `antenna` `insert path` style that takes one argument, namely the number of the coordinate, the rest is a mix of relative (`+`) as well as relative and move-to (`++`) operators.

The same is valid for the `\MBS` macro. Here I have opted to draw the `dart` with an `outer sep` of zero, so that the anchors lie in the middle of line (which needs to go against with drawing the antenna part (notice the `yshift=.8pt` which comes from [the line width used with the `thick` style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106743/16595)).

I commented the original placement of the `\dots` and added another way to place the dots, namely with a `label` (`\MUE`) and a node on a path (`\MBS`).
Feel free to not use this.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{antenna/.style={insert path={-- coordinate (ant#1)  ++(0,0.25) -- + (135:0.25) + (0,0) -- +(45:0.25)}}}
\newcommand{\MUE}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={rectangle,minimum width=+0pt}]
\node[draw, shape = rectangle, minimum width=15mm, minimum height=7.5mm,label=\dots] (box) {#1};

\draw ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (4pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (4pt);
\fill ([xshift=.25cm] box.south west) circle (1pt)
      ([xshift=-.25cm]box.south east) circle (1pt);

\draw ([xshift=.25cm] box.north west) [antenna=1];
\draw ([xshift=-.25cm]box.north east) [antenna=2];

%\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\MBS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, shape = dart, shape border rotate = 90, minimum width = 10mm, minimum height = 10mm,outer sep=+0pt] (base) {#1};

\draw[line join = bevel] (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east) -- cycle;

\draw[line cap=rect] ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=.8pt] base.north) [antenna=1];
\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=.8pt]ant1 |- base.north) -- node[above,shape=rectangle]{\dots} ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=.8pt]base.north) [antenna=2];

%\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, shape = circle, fill = yellow!30] at (0,0) (test1) {\MBS{BS}};

\node[draw, shape = circle, fill = blue!30] at (3,3) (test2) {\MUE{UE1}};
\node[draw, shape = circle, fill = blue!30] at (3,-3) (test3) {\MUE{UE2}};

\draw[->] (test1) -- (test2);
\draw[->] (test1) -- (test3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The only problem with your solution is with placing the `\dots` when I try to use `inner sep = 0pt` in the main nodes, e.g., `\node[inner sep = 0pt]{\UE{UE1}}`. I would use the label as you did, but using `\node at ($(ant1)!0.5!(ant2)$) {\dots};` doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @cacamailg Yes, as you place a TikZ picture inside another TikZ picture, all styles are inherited. This is also true for *your* node but as it uses the `.center` anchor  for placement (and you don't draw it or add something dependent on it you don't see the result). If you want to use my approach you can re-set `inner ysep=+.3333em` (the default if I recall correctly) or even adjust it slightly to place dots better; you can also use the `above` key with a negative/positive distance for vertical placements.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will try it later. Thank you very much.