# Rectangle thickness in Latex Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle, draw, minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.5em] (I) {X};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to personalize the thickness of the lines conforming a rectangle node?

Comment: Certainly, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106742/increase-the-thickness-of-node-border-in-tikz/106743#106743

Comment: I noticed that i cannot use "line width=2mm" together with "thick". 
If I use "\node[rectangle,line width=2mm, draw, minimum height=1.5em, minimum width=1.5em] (I) {X};", It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned in the post I linked to, `thick` is the same as `line width=0.8pt`, so if you use both, the last used will overwrite the first.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you want to write an answer or close it as a duplicate or wait till someone else writes an answer?